# MVC5 Render Javascript and calling functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently working on MVC and I want to create a .js file in the Scripts folder and include this in some of the views. I store all the functions inside a javascript object and I want to call on these outside of the .js file  in the View and i understand this is somewhat problematic. I read that I could use:

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/test.js")

My problem then is that my script bundles which includes Jquery runs after the test.js so my jquery code inside test.js does not work. If there is a way to make @Scripts.Render render after the bundles everything would work.

Example of what I am trying to do:

content of test.js inside /Scripts/ folder:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    const example =
        {
            test: function () {
                console.log('It works');
            }
        }
    });
```

Code in the view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/test.js")
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            example.test();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Is this doable in any way or should i just create a separate .js file for each View? My thought here was that i want a single .js file for multiple Views under the same folder but I do not want to run all the javascript in all those views just call on the functions that i need for that particular View.